# what cause the minor page faults？RSS and VSZ constant

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

The pidstat -r result:

10:53:20          PID  minflt/s  majflt/s     VSZ    RSS   %MEM

10:53:21        15800     48.00      0.00 4859808 4164084  12.74
10:53:22        15800    100.00      0.00 4859808 4164084  12.74
10:53:23        15800     54.00      0.00 4859808 4164084  12.74
10:53:24        15800     35.00      0.00 4859808 4164084  12.74
10:53:25        15800     41.00      0.00 4859808 4164084  12.74
10:53:26        15800     41.00      0.00 4859808 4164084  12.74
10:53:27        15800     29.00      0.00 4859808 4164084  12.74
10:53:28        15800     19.00      0.00 4859808 4164084  12.74
10:53:29        15800     94.00      0.00 4859808 4164084  12.74
10:53:30        15800     28.00      0.00 4859808 4164084  12.74
10:53:31        15800     65.00      0.00 4859808 4164084  12.74

the program use big share memory, about 4G, no other program share the memory;

use pidstat -r to see the statistics, we can see the VSZ and RSS not increase.

and after the program runs for a week, also can see the minor page faults.

so I do not know why?

Comment: Ddoes the proram ever allocate and free memory?

Comment: Not sure about your specific case, but minor page fault usually means the memory required was already in main memory and just needed to be mapped to the process' address space or permissions flags needed to be verified/changed. In other words, a minor page fault is one that doesn't require loading memory from disk (a major page fault).

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the issue where I saw minor page faults, but no RSS increase due to numa page migration: [Can page faults be triggered by NUMA access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70740034/can-page-faults-be-triggered-by-numa-access)